# Format date in title of a panel

Tags: jsf, bootsfaces

How can I format a date as title of a panel in BootsFaces?

```
<b:panel title="#{bean.date}">
    content
</b:panel>
```

Actually my date is displayed like: `2016-05-14 12:00:00.0`.

Can I achieve this without pre formatting the date via Java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BootsFaces doesn't have a date formatter, but there's a nice OmniFaces function you can use:

```
<b:panel title="#{of:formatDate(bean.date, 'dd.MM.yyyy')}">
   content
</b:panel>
```

Comment: You got me! I did not think aboutOmniFaces.

Comment: BootsFaces could also add support for a `<f:facet name="title">` so that more fine grained control is offered for markup of panel's title.